# system.formatexception in while(true) loop

Tags: c#

The subject is a little problem:
Write a program and continuously ask the user to enter a number or "ok" to exit. Calculate the sum of all the previously entered numbers and display it on the console.

Here is my code:

```
    var sum = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or ok to exit:");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "ok") break;
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

When I tap ok, it terminate.
When I tap number and enter, it shows system.formatexception:The input string is not in the correct format.
I know one of the solution is

```
    var sum = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number (or 'ok' to exit): ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input.ToLower() == "ok")
            break;
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(input);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers is: " + sum);
```

Maybe My code looks a little weired, But Why is my code wrong?

Comment: Because after you compare it with `"ok"` you throw away the number input by a user?

Comment: The second solution you show saves the string returned by the Console.ReadLine() into a variable, then if it is not equal to "ok" it converts it into an integer and adds it to the sum proplerly. 
Your initial solution consumes the Console.ReadLine in a comparison with "ok", if the input does not match "ok" then you are converting into an integer A NEW ENTRY by the user because you are calling on Console.ReadLine() again. That is why it does not work.

Comment: I tried the first code in a fiddle (see https://dotnetfiddle.net/4UA4i2) & after inserting a number it strangely asks new number for second time and only the last number inserted will be assigned to sum with. Also it doesn't throw `FormatException` for every number insertion as claimed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is `input` will be "ok". Can not convert that into an integer.

1. first you have to store the first input value into other variable.
2. then convert that string into integer and get summation.

   ```
   var sum = 0;
   while (true)
   {
       Console.Write("Enter a number (or 'ok' to exit): ");
       var input = Console.ReadLine();
       int newVariable = 0;
       if (input.ToLower() != "ok")
       {
           newVariable = Convert.ToInt32(input);
       }

       input = Console.ReadLine();
       if (input.ToLower() == "ok"){
           break;
       sum += newVariable;
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers is: " + sum);
   ```

If there any problem here please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
while (true)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number or ok to exit:");
        String ans = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ans == "ok" || ans.ToLower() == "ok") break;
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(ans);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Here I've just store input entered by user in one variable and use that variable in further process.

In your first code you have take input two times, first one is in IF condition and second in parsing, that may cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use `int.TryParse` for your conversion from a `string` to a number. `TryParse` attempts to convert the string to a number, but if it cannot do so (for example, the string contains more than just numeric digits) it will fail gracefully instead of causing an exception. The other answers so far will all cause an unhandled `FormatException` if something non-numeric is entered other than `"ok"`. By using `int.TryParse` you can handle the case where it's a valid number, as well as the case where it is invalid, and then alert the user. Here's an example within the context of your code:

```
// I prefer using concrete types for numbers like this, so if anyone else
// reads it they know the exact type and numeric limits of that type.
int sum = 0;
int enteredNumber = 0;
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number (or 'ok' to exit): ");
    var consoleInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (consoleInput.ToLower() == "ok")
        break;

    if(int.TryParse(consoleInput, out enteredNumber))
    {
        sum += enteredNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You entered '" + consoleInput + "', which is not a number.");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Sum of all numbers is: " + sum.ToString());
```

This is better because you know you have no control over the user's input other than to validate it yourself, and so it's better to speculatively convert the number and be alerted to success or failure without triggering an exception. Wrapping everything with a try/catch block is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code example, as rightly pointed out in the comments, reads a line, tests it for 'ok', then throws it away, reads another line, and uses that to add to the sum, which is not what you wanted.

After some quick research, I would say the most concise way to handle this in C# is probably something like your second code example. In F# I was able to come up with the following examples (one is a loop, the other uses sequences, i.e. `IEnumerable<_>`s) but I found no *concise* way to get the same with C# and LINQ…

```
let inputLoop () =
    let rec aux sum =
        match stdin.ReadLine () with
        | "ok" -> sum
        | s -> aux (sum + int s)
    stdout.WriteLine (aux 0 |> string)

let inputSeq () =
    fun _ -> stdin.ReadLine ()
    |> Seq.initInfinite
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun s -> s <> "ok")
    |> Seq.sumBy int
    |> string
    |> stdout.WriteLine
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try it :)**

```
var sum = 0;
while (true)
        {
           Console.Write("Enter a number:  or ok to exit : ");
            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "ok" || input.ToLower() == "ok") break;
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            continue;
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(input);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Result: " + sum);
```

*Write a program and continuously ask the user to enter a number or "ok" to exit. Calculate the sum of all the previously entered numbers and display it on the console. Happy Coding*

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Write number or write \"ok\" for exit: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input.ToLower() != "ok")
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(input);
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
Console.WriteLine("All sum: " + sum + ".");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation (by amending your answer) why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. I'm just learning to do this!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number to know the sum or press ok to exit and display the sum");
        int sum = 0;
        while (true) // to run the program continously asking user input
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number: ");
            var input = Console.ReadLine(); // takes user input
            if (input.ToLower() == "ok") // compares user input to string ok
                break; //if user input is ok, breaks the loop and sum is displayed
            var inputInInt = Convert.ToInt32(input); // if user input is int, continues to convert it to integer
            sum += inputInInt; // user input in interger is added to sum
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The sum of entered numbers is: " + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```